# Is there any way to make these connected dots with React Native styles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styles

Do you know if there is a way to do the connected dots that are on the image link below using React Native?

[image of instruction steps using connected dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAApn.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a View with vertical border to conect the dots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).